# Link qt dlls to multiple executables

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, exe

I have four different .exes in differend subdirs of one specific directory. All of the programs need the exact same .dlls (Qt5Core, Qt5Gui and Qt5Widgets). Is there a way of having theese three .dlls just in the root directory insted of having to copy them into each subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you find the order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications) in which DLL paths are searched on Windows:

Since *Safe DLL search mode is enabled by default*, the order is

> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 3. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> 4. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 5. The current directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

So the easiest thing to do is to ensure that you run your app from the working directory where you put the DLLs (5.). That could be done by writing a starter .bat file that navigates there first and then runs the application relative to the DLL direcory.

The other way would be to add the DLL directory to PATH in a starter .bat file (6.).

In both cases you need a wrapper script for each .exe that you want to run.

You could avoid that if you can make sure that links to the application set the working directory properly. This would work if you have an installer creating the shortcuts for the user and you know the user will not create one himself by just right-clicking the .exe.

---

There might also be a way using [hardlinks or junctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I don't know if you can copy and deploy those like symbolic links on Linux or if you need to create them on the target system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are using Windows and you can add your root directory as a path in *Environment Varibles* from

Computer-> Properties->Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

[image]